# Merging objects in List<Object> on two properties

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class Note
{
    public string account;
    public DateTime noteDate;
    public string noteText;
}

List<Note> List1;
```

Using LINQ I'm looking for a way to combine `noteText` where `account` and `noteDate` are the same.  For example, if the incoming list has three objects:

```
List1[0] = "1234", 2017-10-03, "This is a"
List1[1] = "1234", 2017-10-03, " sample note."
List1[2] = "4321", 2017-10-03, "This is another note."
```

I would expect the new list to have two objects:

```
List2[0] = "1234", 2017-10-03, "This is a sample note."
List2[1] = "4321", 2017-10-03, "This is another note."
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I suspect this is doable with a GroupBy plus a select

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is to group by date and account, then `Join` the string fields:

```
List2 = List1.GroupBy(n => new {n.noteDate, n.account})
             .Select(g => new Note {
                 noteDate = g.Key.noteDate,
                 account  = g.Key.account,
                 noteText = string.Join("", g.Select(n => n.noteText))
                 });
```

Comment: Better use `string.Concat` if your separator is an empty string